# Are ViewModels in wpf necessary?

Tags: c#, wpf

this is a newbie question for wpf.
Are ViewModels in wpf useful.
Theres a drive where i work  to convert all our controls to follow the MVVM architecture to create viewmodels.
I dont really grasp or understand why it is useful to spend time refactoring code creating viewmodels...so I am asking you guys if it is worth it.
Basically, what is the use of this mvvm architecture?

Ok, I know that I should do a google search, but I am a starting level programmer for wpf, so when I read articles on google about MVVM, it gives me a conceptual idea of why thats important but Im afraid I dont fully understand the concept from a practical standpoint I guess...
Thanks

Comment: sounds a little open and better suited programmers exchange

Comment: Search for "why mvvm" in your favorite search engine, or on StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=why+mvvm

Comment: there are lots of articles out there already http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx for instance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use MVVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653096/why-use-mvvm)

Comment: @Jodrell - nope. Not suitable (in it's present form) for Programmers. Too open and not constructive.

Answer (score 2):

MVVM is not neccessary, but it helps a lot if your application gets more complex and when you want a clean separation between the view and application logic.

I would recommend you to use MVVM unless your application is very simple.