# Why should i use MVVM?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653096/why-use-mvvm)

I am trying to implement MVVM in my WPF Project, but since i started i am finding hard to accomplish by desired task.

I am using Caliburn Micro for MVVM, I am finding hard to call other other ViewModel property from a ViewModel and also cannot able to handle Event of controls like GotFocus of textBox.

Is MVVM really better than CodeBehind, I am not using MVVM for testing purpose.

Please help.

Comment: There are many many answers here on SO that highlight the importance and need of MVVM. Please read them all and then come back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVVM eases automated testing, and it helps you keep your code clean through a separation of concerns.

If you don't do automated testing, mainly the second reason remains (there are other, minor advantages, but this is the main one IMO). If you're having a hard time with pure MVVM, you might want to consider using a hybrid approach: Keep as much as possible in the view model, but don't be afraid to use code behind if it makes your code more readable.

Don't forget: MVVM is a tool, not a goal! It's supposed to make your life easier, not harder. If you have to write 50 lines of boilerplate code over two layers of indirection just to avoid a single-line GotFocus handler, you might be overdoing it.