# When to use Twitter's Flight Framework?

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-flight

Twitter released their [Javascript Framework Flight](https://github.com/twitter/flight) some days ago on github. From what I have gathered, Flight puts the JS logic behind another layer, where the separate components can only be accessed via specific event calls (like an API?).

I'm not quite sure I understand the benefits of using a JS Framework and what Flight brings to the table. Would I use this if I made a mobile application to improve performance <strike>(JS on serverside?)</strike> and better control what events call components?

Here are some of the articles/relate posts I could find so far:

- [InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/02/Twitter-Flight)
- [blogeek](http://www.blogeek.com.ar/2013/01/31/twitters-flight-js-framework-first-thoughts-and-comparison-with-backbone/)
- [SO: Why do we need JS Frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838395/why-do-we-need-backbone-js-or-any-js-mvc-framework)

Comment: it's a layer of abstraction, useful for big projects in which it's often difficult to clearly separate code and keep it maintainable. I.e: separation of concerns (SOC). (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). This, imho, should be the most important goal of ANY client-side framework / mvc . Twitter Flight notably separates itself from other JS-frameworks , particularly MVC's (model-view-controller, look it up. Another way to de SOC, by completely separating client-side assets (js, templates, css) out in widgets. So widgets can be created independently. SOC at it's fullest.