# Make ListView Item Selected Form ItemSource

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a ListView like this

```
<ListView x:Name="lview" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I am binding data to this Listview like this

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ObservableCollection<OptionItem> io = new ObservableCollection<OptionItem>();
    io.Add(new OptionItem { Name = "11111111111", IsSelected=false });
    io.Add(new OptionItem { Name = "22222222222", IsSelected=true });
    io.Add(new OptionItem { Name = "33333333333", IsSelected=true });
    io.Add(new OptionItem { Name = "44444444444",IsSelected=false });

    lview.ItemsSource = io;
}
```

Now you can see inside my Model, I have a Property called `IsSelected`. How can I bind this to the listView, so that the Items selected in the `ItemsSource` comes as selected in ListView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on when you want the selection to happen, subscribe to an event of the `ListView` where you add the selected `OptionItem`s to the list of selected items:

**Code**

```
private void Lview_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listView = sender as ListView;
    foreach (OptionItem item in listView.Items)
    {
        if (item.IsSelected)
        {
            listView.SelectedItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="lview" SelectionMode="Multiple" SizeChanged="Lview_SizeChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Anyway you probably want to consider using a pattern like [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653096/why-use-mvvm/20524980) as this will make your code (by far!) more readable and easier to maintain.